# For Loop keeps restarting in EMR (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, memory-leaks, nested-loops, amazon-emr

I have a nested for loop that performs operations on a data frame 10 times in the inner loop and joins the resulting 10 data frames into a single data frame once it finishes the inner loop.

***UPDATE:*** *I use a dictionary to create a list of dataframes to store each operation in and then union them at the end of the inner loop.*

It then writes it to a parquet file with the iteration number of the outloop.
The outerloop has 6 iterations and therefore should result in 6 parquet files.

It goes something like this:

```
train=0
for i in range(0,6):
    train=train+30
    #For loop to aggregate input and create 10 output dataframes
    dfnames={}
    for j in range(0,10):
        ident="_"+str(j)  
        #Load dataframe of around 1M rows
        df=spark.read.parquet("s3://path")
        dfnames['df'+ident]= #Perform aggregations and operations
    #Combine the 10 datframes into a single df
    df_out=df_1.uniionByName(d_2).unionByName(df_3)...unionByName(df_10)
    #Write to output parquet file
    df_out.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("s3://path/" + str(train) +".parquet"
```

It seems to be working fine until it finishes the 3rd iteration of the outer loop. Then for some reason, it restarts the loop with another attempt id.
So I get the first 3 files, but instead of going to the 4th iteration, it restarts to give the first file all over again. I dont get any failed stages or jobs.

I have tried running the for loops alone with dummy variables and print statements (without loading the large data frames etc) and they work fine to completion.
I am thinking it has something to do with the way the memory is being flushed after a loop.

These are my EMR Spark running conditions:
I am running this on an EMR cluster with 5 executors, 5 driver nodes, and 10 instances with a total of 50 cores. The spark executor and driver memory is 45G each with a total of about 583G.
The typical shuffle read is 250G and shuffle write is 331G.

Some of the pertinent Spark environment variables are shown below:

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong with regards to the loop or memory management?
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not combine Python data structures with Spark data structures.

**You want to convert the for loops into a **map-reduce, foreach** form of design.**

Along with this, you can create a cache/ spark checkpoint in each iteration to avoid rerunning the entire DAG from scratch.

To cache your data:

```
df.cache()
```

for checkpointing

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('<some path>')
df.checkpoint()
```

These will show performance and scale improvement once you use the spark constructs instead of python constructs. For example, replace your for loop by *foreach*, replace union of a list by *map reduce*.

Comment: By Python data structures, do you mean the `dfnames[]` dictionary?
How do I create spark checkpoints?

Comment: Yes dfnames is a dictionary, along with that list, set etc. are python datastructures, while RDD and DataFrames are PySpark data structures.

Comment: So I looked into `foreach()` and it seems that it works only for RDD. I cannot use it on dataframes. Is there another way to substitute the for loops?

Answer (score 1):

How are you getting your df1, df2... before this line?

`#Combine the 10 datframes into a single df df_out=df1.uniionByName(d2).unionByName(df3)...unionByName(df10)`

My guess is, your dataframe plan is growing big and that might be causing issues.

I would suggest creating a list of dataframes in the inner loop and use `reduce` method to union them.

Something like below

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
df_list = []
for j in range(0,10):  
        #Load dataframe of around 1M rows
        df = spark.read.parquet("s3://path")
        transformed_df = #do your transforms
        df_list.append(transformed_df)

final_df = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, df_list)
```

Comment: I updated my post to show that part. I use a dictionary `dfnames` to store the generated 10 dataframes as `df_1`, `df_2`, df_3` etc.. and then unionByName. 
each of those 10 dataframes is unique and I would like to simply union them after the inner loop. Would the ``reduce` method modify the contents in any way?
Also wouldnt the `append` function keep the contents of the appended dfs in a single node as opposed to distributed?

Comment: The `reduce` method will not modify contents. It just applies a particular function passed in its argument to all of the list elements.
`append` is just appending dataframes to a list, and dataframes are just plans, they do not contain any data. Basically , your list will have references to each transformation for each iteration.
Something like this `[DataFrame[comment: bigint, inp_col: string, input_val: string], DataFrame[comment: bigint, inp_col: string, input_val: string], DataFrame[comment: bigint, inp_col: string, input_val: string]]`

Comment: I tried the `append` method. But I got a Memory Heap error :(